# Finding the Differential Equation using Parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was supposed to find the differential equation of the equation $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=a^2$$ where $a$ is a given constant.

I did it the normal way by differentiating once to get an equation in terms of $(x-h)$ and $(y-k)$. Then differentiating it once more to get $(y-k)$ in terms of $y'$ and $y''$. Then substituting it in the first equation to get $(x-k)$ in terms of $y'$ and $y''$. Then substituting it in the original equation. Finally, I got the differential equation as $$[1+(y')^2]^3=a^2y''^2$$

However, I thought of another simpler way. Assume $$x-h=a\:cos\theta,\;\;y-k=a\:sin\theta$$
$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-a\:sin\theta,\;\;\frac{dy}{d\theta}=a\:cos\theta$$ $$\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}=-a\:cos\theta,\;\;\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}=-a\:sin\theta$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-cot\theta,\;\;\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=tan\theta$$

Hence, I get the differential equation as $$y'y''+1=0$$

Is my second method valid? Since I'm supposed to solve such types of sums in less than $3$ minutes, I find second method a lot easier.

I would also like to know if there's some other simple method to find the differential equation of such equations.

**EDIT:** I have uploaded the steps to the first method.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your second method. $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ is not equal to $\tan \theta$. It's more complicated.

With the first method, your result  $[1+(y')^2]^3=a^2y''$ is not correct : try to solve this ODE and see that the solution is not $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=a^2$ as expected. Since you didn't published the details of the calculus, it is not possible to see where is the mistake.

My result is :
$$[1+(y')^2]^{3/2}=-a y''$$

Comment: Please see the edit. I didn't find anything wrong in that. Still, I'll try once to solve the ODE. Though to my misfortune, I don't have enough expertise to solve second degree differential equations.

Comment: I agree with your new edit : $$[1+(y')^2]^3=a^2y''^2$$ In your first answer (before the edit), you forgot the power $2$ of $y''^2$. Now, it is consistent with my result $$[1+(y')^2]^{3/2}=-ay''$$ in selecting the convenient sign of the square root.

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks for noticing! Can you explain why the second method fails, and if I were to follow the second method, what differential equation would I end up with?

Comment: As already said, the second method fails because your second derivative $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\tan(\theta)$ is false. With the correct expression $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-\frac{1}{a\sin^3(\theta)}$ one end up with the same differential equation than the first method.

Comment: Use the chain rule : $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}(-\cot\theta)\right)\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$

Comment: So you mean $$\cfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}\;\;\text{is not equal to}\cfrac{\cfrac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}}{\cfrac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}}$$

Comment: I donno why the \ne is not working in the comment.

Comment: Do not confuse $\frac{dy}{dx}$ or $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ with fractions. They are symbols for operations which are not division but differentiation. That's not the same. In $\frac{\frac{d^2y}{d\theta^2}}{\frac{d^2x}{d\theta^2}}$ you cannot simplify $d\theta^2$. Only in case of first derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ it "behaves like" a fraction. But "behaves like" doesn't mean "is". When you simplify $\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ you do a short-cut for something very different from a simple simplification of $d\theta$ : There is behind a theoretically proved calculus.

Comment: Yeah. I had come across a proof of it. The correct expression for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ in the fourth comment works. Thanks! Just a small request. Please edit your answer to include these points. :)

Comment: Hi Tejas ! Since you already made a partial correction in your first post, why not continue on this way and yourself edit the full corrected version ? I did my part of the job as requested : showing that the method was valid but mistaked and pointing out where exactly was the mistake.